# How to update np.array conditionally?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, conditional-statements

I got two numpy arrays:

```
Out[23]: a = np.array([3, 7, 8, 9, 2], dtype=float)
Out[24]: b = np.array([5, 6, 7, 10, 3], dtype=float)
```

I need to compare a and b, and update array b so that its elements will contain
the higher value or np.nan

Example code:

```
for i in range(len(b)):
    b[i] = b[i] if b[i] > a[i] else np.nan
```

Result:

```
b
Out[33]: array([  5.,  nan,  nan,  10.,   3.])
```

Is there a way to do this without using a for loop?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
>>> np.where(b > a, b, np.nan)
array([  5.,  nan,  nan,  10.,   3.])
```

Comment: Thank you so much !
I wish I had a better knowledge of Numpy API.
;-)

Answer (score 1):

Using `np.where` to evaluate the condition across the vector

```
b = np.where(b>a,b,np.nan)
```

np.where takes a `(condition, value_when_true, value_when_false)`

Answer (score 1):

```
b[b <= a] = np.nan
```

Demo:

```
>> import numpy as np
>> a = np.array([3, 7, 8, 9, 2], dtype=float)
>> b = np.array([5, 6, 7, 10, 3], dtype=float)
>> b[b <= a] = np.nan
>> b
array([  5.,  nan,  nan,  10.,   3.])
```